# How do I force the browser to update its base URL

Tags: http, redirect, curl

I have a PHP script that uses CURL to fetch a remote page and return the output as is. It displays fine in the browser, but the problem is, when I click a link it is still using the old base url. Can I force the browser with some kind of HTTP Header or something to use the base url of the server that I fetched the page from in my PHP script?

Comment: Are you sure the URL was relative? It may have been a full absolute URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can inject into the source you could use a [base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp) and set the href to the base page you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a PHP script that uses CURL to
>   fetch a remote page and return the
>   output as is

So do not output it as is, parse and replace URL and only then output it.